# Figuring out type declaration for HOF in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, definition, type-declaration

I am reviewing for an exam and one of the practice problems ask to write the type declaration

```
mystery :: ---complete here---- 
mystery x p
    | p (head x) = tail x
    | otherwise  = head x : mystery (tail x) p
```

Without looking at the answer, I thought mystery would be of type:

`mystery:: [a] -> a -> [a]`

but when I look at the solution to compare:

`mystery:: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]`

Why is `a -> Bool`? and what in the lines of code can tell me to consider `Bool` in my type declaration ?

Comment: What's your thought process with  `mystery :: [a] -> a -> [a]`? Finding types is more an exercise of logic than anything else; if you can explain that, you can work out where you went wrong.

Comment: "what in the lines of code can tell me to consider `Bool` in my type declaration?" The call to `p` is used as a predicate in a guard, which is always type `Bool`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what we know about `p`:

1. It is applied to a value, so it must be a function. That makes its type `t1 -> t2` for some types `t1` and `t2`.
2. It is specifically applied to `head x`. Since you've already determined that `x :: [a]`, then `head x :: a`. This means `t1 ~ a`, and so `p :: a -> t2`.
3. `p (head x)` is used in a context where a Boolean value is expected, so `p (head x) :: Bool`. This means `t2 ~ Bool`, and so `p :: a -> Bool`.

QED.